# Py2app - how to build single app for Intel and Silicon

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, py2app, apple-silicon

I have built a python application uisng Py2app to compile it into a .app using a Mac Pro with an Intel CPU, this runs fine on other Intel CPU Macs.
I have also built the same python application uisng Py2app to compile it into a .app using a new Macbook with an M1 chip, this runs fine on other Silicon CPU Macs, but won't run on Intel macs.
My question is, how can I build a single app which runs on both Intel and Silicon Macs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a "Universal Binary" from two apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300218/create-a-universal-binary-from-two-apps)